# Sequential parameter estimation of multiple discrete random walks

Tags: hypothesis-testing, random-walk, sequential-analysis

We have $M$ Bernoulli random walks, $X_1$ has parameter $p< 1/2$ and all the rest have parameter $1/2$. The steps are $\pm 1$. I want to identify the parameter $p$ random walk with probability of error less than $\epsilon$ and I want to know how many samples I need to do it (one sample = one observation from each of the $M$ walks). After searching math.SE and google, I had difficulty finding any literature on this problem, which is kind of surprising given that it seems like a fundamental and interesting problem.

My naive guess as a non-statistician would be that one should set up some kind of optimal Neyman-Pearson like threshold for the $M$ random walks and then let $P($error$)= P(\exists k:\tau_k < \tau_1)$ where $\tau_k$ is the time until walk $k$ reaches this threshold.

Looking at this formulation, I would guess that this problem becomes analytically intractable quite quickly unless you are okay with union bounding the error probability. Am I getting close here? I would very much appreciate any references on this problem, even the specific name for this problem (if it has one) or where one might look for related problems.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, you can simply use [Hoeffding’s inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality).

For each random walk $X$, let's define the corresponding Bernoulli jumps:
$$
Y^{(j)}=\begin{cases}
1, & \mbox{if  } X^{(j+1)}- X^{(j)}=1,\\
0, & \mbox{if  } X^{(j+1)}- X^{(j)}=-1.
\end{cases}
$$ 
Then $Y^{(1)},\ldots,Y^{(n)}\sim\mbox{Bernoulli}(p)$, where $p<1/2$ for the first random walk and $p=1/2$ for the remaining $M-1$ walks. Then, for any $\delta>0$, 
$$
\mathbb{P}(|\overline{Y}_n-p|>\delta)\leq 2e^{-2n\delta^2},
$$
where $\overline{Y}_n$ is the sample mean, $\overline{Y}_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nY^{(j)}$. Given the accuracy of estimation $\delta$ and probability of error $\epsilon$, you can find the required number of samples from the following equation
$$
2e^{-2n\delta^2}=\epsilon,
$$
which yields 
$$
n=\frac{1}{2\delta^2}\ln\frac{2}{\epsilon}.
$$

Comment: The issue is that I'm not really estimating the parameter, it is known a priori that one of them has parameter p.

Comment: Ah, I see, you want to find the walk with known parameter $p<1/2$. But can't we just simply tweak the above solution a bit? At each step, the walk with the smallest mean $\overline{Y}_n$ is the candidate for being the target p-walk. Set $\delta=1/2-\overline{Y}_n$ for that walk. Use this $\delta$ and the current value of $n$ to find the error $\epsilon$. Continue until the error is less than the required error.

Comment: Yes I think this could certainly produce an efficient algorithm for finding the walk, but I don't think it will produce an analytic a priori bound on the required sample size.